# How can I efficiently search for many strings at once in many files?

Tags: python, shell, csv, awk

Hi i post my portion of code and then i'll explain my goal:

```
for eachcsv in matches:
    with open(eachcsv, 'r') as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
        for entry in rs:
            for line in lines:
                if entry in line:
                    print("found %s in %s" % (entry, eachcsv))
```

So in "matches" i got a list of csv files (the path to them). I open every csv file and i load them into memory with readlines(). "rs" is a list of unique ids. For every element of the list "rs" i need to search every line of the csv file and print each time i find the id on the file (later on i will test if the line contains another fixed word also).

The code above works for my purpose but i don't know why it takes more than 10 minutes to process a 400k row file, i need to do this task for thousand of files so it's impossible for me to finish the task. It seems to me that the slow part is the testing process, but i'm not sure.

Please note that i use python because i'm more confortable with it, if there is ANY other solution to my problem using other tools i'm ok with it.

EDIT:
i will try to post some examples

```
"rs" list:
rs12334435
rs3244567
rs897686
....

files

# header data not needed
# data
# data
# data
# data
# data [...]
#COLUMN1    COLUMN2               COLUMN3   ...
data        rs7854.rs165463       dataSS=1(random_data)
data        rs465465data          datadata
data        rs798436              dataSS=1  
data        datars45648           dataSS=1
```

The final goal is to count how many times every rs appers on each file and if in column 3 there is SS=1 to flag it in the output.
Something like

```
found rs12345 SS yes file 3 folder /root/foobar/file
found rs74565 SS no file 3 folder /root/foobar/file
```

Comment: try to cut your innermost loop to instead search the line itself with regex or string search

Comment: Well, if `n` is the number of files, `m` is the number of ids, `k` is the average number of lines and `l` is the number of characters per line, we are looking at O(nmkl) here, which is slow for large files unsurprisingly.

Comment: Yes but still it's linear so i wouldn't expect hundreds of years as i'm getting

Comment: Would `for line in f:` instead of `lines = f.readlines(); for line in lines:` help with speed at all, since it wouldn't have to load 400k lines into memory before starting to loop?

Comment: @BlueStarry it's far from linear. Suppose n=l=m=k, then it's O(n^4)

Comment: Yea you're right. @timgeb But still, i need to find a way to solve this. The only thing i can do is to cut unwanted portions from the files maybe but how...

Comment: Can you post some examples of ids and lines? The only room for improvement I see is using a more efficient approach to search a line. Also, try PyPy

Comment: @BlueStarry have you tried jonhopkins' suggestion? Might very well be a memory issue.

Comment: If an item appears more than once in a given csv file, should that file be listed more than once in your output?  Or is it sufficient to list the file a single time?

Comment: @IanMcLaird i can't break off the for because i need to count them

Comment: You should concat all your ids in a big regex. And apply this regex to each line. This would reduce the complexity from O(nmkl) to O(nkl).

Comment: I mean, compile a big regex that looks like this: (?<!\d)(56|58|907|780|89|900)(?!\d), an apply it on each line (assuming your ids are numerical).

Comment: @JohnSmithOptional - I'm not sure that'll work for him, since he needs to show how many of each ID are contained in each file.

Comment: I don't think that prevents from keeping a count of the matches for each file.

Comment: Thanks everyone so far, @DanielHepper i've got the example for you and everyone.

Comment: Another approach: put the ids in a set; read the files using the csv module; for each row in the file ask the set if the id is an interesting one.  That moves the "is this id interesting" from O(n) to O(1) since it is a simple hash-based lookup.  This assumes the CSV data has real structure and you know which column(s) contain the ids. Similarly, if you can match just the relevant column instead of searching the entire line for the substring ...

Comment: Another note: since the files are so large, they won't fit in a single (or few) pages of memory to reside in the CPU's cache.  Thus repeatedly iterating through `lines` slows down the CPU due to the overhead of memory accesses (specifically the cache misses). Reordering it to loop through the file once and assuming the number of ids is smaller will give you better speed with respect to memory access.

Comment: @dsh I would use the csv module BUT if you look closer on the example the top portion of the files is full of garbage starting with #

Comment: @BlueStarry Ah, right. In that case open the file, read the first few lines, then pass the open file to the csv module so that it starts after those "headers". Eg: `while f.peek(1) == '#': f.readline();` `reader = csv.reader(f)`

Comment: Hey @dsh f.peek gives me error, is there any other way to achieve this?? BEcause it says that file object has no attribute peek

Comment: There are other ways. [`peek()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html?highlight=peek#io.BufferedReader.peek) is nice because it leaves the character in the stream so the first character of the first "real" row isn't missing when you hand the stream to the csv reader. The method is on the `io.BufferedReader` class, so you will probably want to use that to access your file.

Comment: Try `grep -Ff rs $(head -10 matches)` to search in the first 10 files and if that works use `GNU Parallel` to do them all fast in parallel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Much of the problem is because you have so many nested loops.  You can probably make your program faster by eliminating loops:

1. One of the loops is over each of the lines in the file.  But if all
   you want to do is determine whether any of the matches exists in the
   file, you can search the whole file body in one operation.   To be
   sure, this searches a longer string, but it does so in one operation
   in native code instead of doing it in Python.
2. You loop over all the match strings.   But you know those before you
   start and they are the same for each file.   So this is a good case
   of when doing-more up-front work will pay off in time saved in the
   rest of the program.   [Stand back, I'm going to use a regular
   expression](https://xkcd.com/208/).

Here is a version of the code which combines these two ideas:

```
import re
import random
import sys
import time

# get_patterns makes up some test data.
def get_patterns():
    rng = random.Random(1)  # fixed seed, for reproducibility
    n = 300
    # Generate up to n unique integers between 60k and 80k.
    return list(set([str(rng.randint(60000, 80000)) for _ in xrange(n)]))

def original(rs, matches):
    for eachcsv in matches:
        with open(eachcsv, 'r') as f:
            lines = f.readlines()
            for entry in rs:
                for line in lines:
                    if entry in line:
                        print("found %s in %s" % (entry, eachcsv))

def mine(rs, matches):
    my_rx = re.compile(build_regex(rs))
    for eachcsv in matches:
        with open(eachcsv, 'r') as f:
            body = f.read()
            matches = my_rx.findall(body)
            for match in matches:
                print "found %s in %s" % (match, eachcsv)

def build_regex(literal_patterns):
    return "|".join([re.escape(pat) for pat in literal_patterns])

def print_elapsed_time(label, callable, args):
    t1 = time.time()
    callable(*args)
    t2 = time.time()
    elapsed_ms = (t2 - t1) * 1000
    print "%8s: %9.1f milliseconds" % (label, elapsed_ms)


def main(args):
    rs = get_patterns()
    filenames = args[1:]
    for function_name_and_function in (('original', original), ('mine', mine)):
        name, func = function_name_and_function
        print_elapsed_time(name, func, [rs, filenames])
    return 0

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
```

Your original code is in there as `original` and my replacement is `mine`.
For 300 patterns, my implementation runs in 400ms on my computer. which is roughly a 30x speedup.  For more match strings, the improvement should be greater.  Doubling the number of patterns roughly doubles the runtime of your implementation, but the regex-based one only takes about 3% longer (though this is partly because my test patterns all have similar prefixes and that may not be true for the real data).

Edit: updated code to print one message for each match.  My code is now somewhat slower, but it's still an improvement, and should be relatively speaking faster with more strings to match:

```
~/source/stackoverflow/36923237$ python search.py example.csv
found green fox in example.csv
original:    9218.0 milliseconds
found green fox in example.csv
    mine:     600.4 milliseconds
```

*Edit*: explanation of the regex technique, as requested.

Suppose you want to search your file for the strings foobar and umspquux.  One way to do this is to search the file for first foobar and then umspquux.  This is the approach you started with.

Another approach is to search for both strings at once.  Imagine that you check the first character of the file.   If it's 'f' or 'u', you might be looking at a match, and should check the second character to see if it, respectively 'o' or 'm'.  And so on.   If you get to the end od of the file, you will have found all the matches there qre in the file to find.

A convenient way to tell a computer to look for multiple strings at once is to use a regular expression.   Normal strings are regular expressions.  The regular expression 'foobar' matches the sub-string 'foobar'  inside 'the foobar is all fuzzy'.   However, you can do more complex things.  You can combine two regular expressions, each of which matches something, into a combined regular expression which will match either of those somethings.  This is done with the alternation symbol, '|'.   So the regular expression 'foobar|umspquux' will match either 'foobar' or 'umspquux'.   You can also match a real '|' by *escaping* the significance of the '|' with a backslash '\'.

This is what the `build_regex_literal_patterns` is all about.   It would convert the list ['foobar', 'umspquux'] into the string 'foobar|umspquux'.   Try it out - put the function definition into your own file and call it with some try-out arguments to see how it behaves.

That's a good way, by the way, to figure out how any piece of code works - run part of it and print the intermediate result.  This is harder to do safely with programs that have side-effects of course, but this program doesn't.

The call to `re.escape` in `build_regex_literal_patterns` simply ensures that any special regular expression operators (such as '|') are escaped (giving in this case '\|') so that they will match themselves.

The last part of the regular expression method here is to use the *findall* method of the compiled regular expression.  This simply returns all the matches for our regular expression in the input string (i.e. the body of the file).

You can read up on Python regular expressions in the [Python documentation on regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html). That documentation is basically reference material, so you might find the gentler introduction at the [Google Develoeprs site has an introduction to Python regular expressions](https://developers.google.com/edu/python/regular-expressions#basic-examples) better as a starting point.  [Jeffrey Friedl's *Mastering Regular Expressions*](https://github.com/shihyu/Regular_Expressions/blob/master/Oreilly.Mastering.Regular.Expressions.3rd.Aug.2006.pdf) is a pretty comprehensive work on regular expressions, thought it doesn't  happen to cover the Python dialect of regular expressions.

Comment: Thank you very much i really appreciate your work but i don't understand if your code is able to print ALL the occurencies in the file i.e. the search function will print 100 times if a particular  rs is found 100 times. Again, thank you very much.

Comment: I can't stress enough how thankful i am. But i've got one last question. I know something on regular expressions from perl, but i can't grasp the concept behind your idea for the regex side.

Comment: Explained.   But try taking the program apart to see what the separate bits do.   It's a valuable technique for understanding code.

Answer (score 0):

Your largest memory intensive operation is going to be reading every line, this should be on the outer loop.

You'll also not want to read the entire document in at once with readlines, use readline instead. Readline is much less memory intensive.

```
for eachcsv in matches:
    with open(eachcsv, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            for entry in rs:
                if entry in line:
                    print("found %s in %s" % (entry, eachcsv))
```

More reading here https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html

There are other optimizations you can take too that fall outside the scope of this question, such as using threading, or using multi processing to read in many csv files at the same time. https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html

```
import threading

def findRSinCSVFile(csvFile,rs)
    with open(csvFile, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            for entry in rs:
                if entry in line:
                    print("found %s in %s" % (entry, eachcsv))

for csvFile in csvFiles():
    threads.append(threading.Thread(target=findRSinCSVFile,args=(csvFile,rs)))

for thread in threads:
    thread.start()
for thread in threads:
    thread.join()
```

This will allow you to parse all the csv files at the same time.

(Note I have not tested any of this code, and only serves as an example)